# Where to download a whole set of maven repository jar files?

Tags: java, maven

Because my repository misses some jar files. I want to redownload the whole repository again. where can I download it?
Like this:
[Maven Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22xXr.jpg)

Comment: If you have a project that is using Maven, then when you try to compile or build that project, the dependencies will be automatically downloaded - this is one of the main uses of maven.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean..
As upper comment says, maven will automatically download the dependent jar files once if you had described in pom.xml.

Or.. if you want to force re-download the whole jar files,
then just remove folders in .m2/repository/ and re-update or build mvn project again.